# How to I get a total count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, percentage

My current query returns the total number of people in each ethnic group as expected, for example:

```
Name        |   Count
----------------------
White       |   22
Asian       |   15
Black       |   12
```

Etc. However I want to add a thrid column which returns each ethnic group as a percentage of the total, how would I go about this?

```
SELECT 
    eo.EthnicOriginName, 
    ISNULL(e.Number, '')
    --CAST(e.Number AS FLOAT) / CAST(COUNT(e.intEthnicOriginID) AS FLOAT)  * 100 

FROM 
    tblEthnicOrigin eo
    INNER JOIN tblPerson p ON p.intEthnicOriginID = eo.EthnicOriginID

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT intEthnicOriginID, COUNT(p.intPersonID) [Number]
            FROM tblPerson p
            INNER JOIN tblClient c on c.intPersonID = p.intPersonID
            GROUP BY intEthnicOriginID) e on e.intEthnicOriginID = eo.EthnicOriginID

GROUP BY
    eo.EthnicOriginName, e.Number
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle or ...)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Then Gordon's answer should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases, you would use ANSI-standard window functions:

```
SELECT eo.EthnicOriginName, COUNT(*) as num,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM tblEthnicOrigin eo INNER JOIN
     tblPerson p
     ON p.intEthnicOriginID = eo.EthnicOriginID
GROUP BY eo.EthnicOriginName;
```

The `* 1.0` is simply because some databases do integer division, and we don't want integer division.